# Theming sencha touch list

Tags: list, themes, sencha-touch, extjs

I want to change the color of the headers in a grouped list. For the moment I've got the default theme. I think I have to use something like "$list-header-bg-color" but :

- WHERE can I use it ? I tried to write something like :

  $list-header-bg-color = '#CCC'

directly at the end of the "sencha-touch.css" file but it doesn't work at all ... Somebody can explain me how does it works ? (with a little example please). Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First you need to install ruby

then install ruby gems

then install compass

then open your application *.scss file (should be in resources/sass/)

after the line

```
@import 'sencha-touch/default/all';
```

include your line

```
$list-header-bg-color = '#CCC'
```

Note that by default the value of this var is

```
$list-header-bg-color: transparentize(saturate($base-color, 10%), .25);
```

Maybe you can change the base-color to have a more "unified" look (depending on what you want to do ...)

then compile your scss file

```
compass compile
```

Now your theme should have been compiled to your app.css and your new color is good :)

For more detail check this article I wrote not long ago : [sass-for-sencha-touch-2-windows-7](http://one2teamdev.blogspot.fr/2012/08/sass-for-sencha-touch-2-windows-7.html)

Answer (score 3):

Sencha is using SASS for theming. So that line should go in the sencha-touch.scss file. Then you should compile that file with compass to get a css file. See this videos:

- http://vimeo.com/26506883
- http://vimeo.com/17879651

  - slides from presentation http://www.slideshare.net/senchainc/theming-sencha-touch
  - reference docs http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/touch/docs/theme/

Check this also http://www.sencha.com/blog/sencha-touch-theme-contest-winners-announced/